# How do I output a file’s URL in a Matrix field?

Tags: matrix, blocks

I have a Matrix field with Image, Caption, and PDF sub-fields. I can output the Image and Caption fine, but am having no luck with the PDF file.

Here is the code:

```twig
{% for block in entry.seriesInformation %}
    {% if block.type == "bladeImage" %}

        {% set image = block.image.first() %}

        {% if image %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('bladesdetail') }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('bladesdetail') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('bladesdetail') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
        {% endif %}

    {% elseif block.type == "caption" %}

        {{ block.caption }}

    {% elseif block.type == "bladeBrochure" %}

        <p><a href="{{ bladeBrochure.url }}">Download &rarr;</a></p>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Brett, welcome to the Craft Stack Exchange site! I’ve edited your question a bit to make it more clear, and removed your second question about creating a Blog. Please post that as a separate question so it can have its own direct set of answers.

Comment: Tried both neither works. It gives me. A URL of PDF/filename. But does not download the file.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the field where your client can select the download is an asset field, you can use the following:

```
{% elseif block.type == "bladeBrochure" %}
    {% set download = block.download.first() %}
    {% if download %}
        <a href="{{ download.url }}">Click me to download</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Replacing `block.download` with the name of your field.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that your PDF field is an assets field? If so, it works exactly the same way as images, and you can output it using something like this:

```
{% for block in entry.matrixFieldHandle %}
    {% set pdf = block.pdfFieldHandle.first() %}
    <a href="{{pdf.getUrl}}">Text</a>
{% endfor %}`
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Brandon; for some reason the 4-space indent just wasn't turning it into code earlier!